# Need to switch back to windows 7. and remove this error to resolve grub: Panic occured, Switching back to text console

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, windows

I am having Acer aspire 4755. I initially had windows7. But tried Ubuntu 12.04. It was working fine. But when I tried to install Windows 7, i got this grub error. I am sure, I must have screwed up the grub file. So when I tried to run a live USB, DVD of Ubuntu back again to install Ubuntu , I got this error: panic occurred, switching back to text console. I even can't install Windows 7 with its starter CD. Kindly help me to remove Ubuntu or remove Grub and get my windows 7 working. I know I have to get the grub working, but how.??

[image]

Comment: Even I tried supergrub [link](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/sgd2_2.00s1b1_main_screen.png)

The link shows image. I tried everything. it doesn't work.

Comment: http://i50.tinypic.com/2hehkk1.jpg

Comment: what you meant by ` I even can't install Windows 7 with its starter CD` . If you start the dvd, it would not start grub in your hard disk. Can you describe more of your steps?

Comment: I got windows 7 starter cd, when I boot using that, it hungs up at the windows logo after showing windows loading files.

Comment: and when I use Ubuntu live cd or Usb, it gets me the error message : Panic occured, Switching back to text console; when I click anything related with install, or try, or even test. Even I tried to resolve grub using supergrub, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Windows may take some time load. Probably its a hardware issue, it would be better if you had test for RAM and Hard Disk.

Comment: I kept for more than 3 hours. nothing happens. I mean I let Windows Starter CD to get me the option to edit the HD, but nothing works

Answer (score 1):

You can replace Grub with Windows 7 boot-loader, simply boot from Windows 7 installer and rewrite the `mbr` from the console, or if you are lucky it automatically corrects it.

Comment: I am not getting the console(cmd pmt). When I use Windows 7 starter, it directly goes to windows loading files and than the logo pops up and thats it.. DVD stops reading. nothing happens

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and add how exactly the user will rewrite the `mbr` from the console?